# PHP Include menu

Tags: php, include

Having trouble wrapping my brain around this as I am a novice at php. But I have a menu that I am currently working on that, depending on what page your on, will have an "active" classes added to it to help the user easily identify what page they are on.

What I would like to do, is add ONE include for the menu, and use PHP code to display the active class on a certain menu element depending on what page they are on. I hope this makes sense, here is the page I am working on:

http://www.motorcityline.com/client/diversden

Comment: can you post the php code that you have till now ?

Comment: I would use an include and put the menu in the header, however I can't do that right now because I don't know how to use the PHP if/else etc statements. So as of right now there is no PHP code for the menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is rough but might be a starting point for you.

```
<li class="MenuItem <? if(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])=='WhateverPage.php') echo 'Selected'; ?>">Menu Name</li>
```

Which is basically just going to check the current PHP file name and add a "Selected" class if it equals. The downfall here is if theres multiple pages representing the same menu item, you would have to add more conditionals.

Comment: Interesting, I will try that now.